# Unable to set invalidProductIdentifiers in SKProductsResponse mock

Tags: swift, unit-testing

I'm trying to unit test my payment module, and for that I'm trying to mock SKProductsResponse and the property return by it.

I started with the products property and it worked fine. but when I try the same thing with the invalidProductIdentifiers that breaks at run time... Here is the code

First I tried by extending the class

```
class ProductsResponse:SKProductsResponse
{
    init(products:[SKProduct], invalidProducts:[String])
    {
        super.init()
        self.setValue(products, forKey: "products")
        self.setValue(invalidProducts, forKey: "invalidProductIdentifiers")
    }
}
```

then by making an extension

```
extension SKProductsResponse
{
    convenience init(products:[SKProduct], invalidProducts:[String]) {
        self.init()
        self.setValue(products, forKey: "products")
        self.setValue(invalidProducts, forKey: "invalidProductIdentifiers")
    }
}
```

Both lead to the same problem, but only for invalidProductIdentifiers ->
 caught "NSUnknownKeyException", "[ProductsResponse setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key invalidProductIdentifiers."

Do you have any idea why or any alternative to this approach? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I still don't know what's going on but I realised that I can simply override the getter of the "invalidProductIdentifiers" like that :

```
override var invalidProductIdentifiers: [String] {get{ return invalidIds}}
private var invalidIds:[String] = []
init(products:[SKProduct], invalidProducts:[String])
{
    super.init()
    invalidIds = invalidProducts
}
```

And that works fine.